# Ratio of cubic and quadratic form in random variables is approximately normal?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, quadratic-form

Let be $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ i.i.d. random variables following a normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. I'm intrigued by the following random variable, which is a ratio of a cubic form and a quadratic form:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\frac{x_1 x_2^2 + x_1 x_3^2 +x_2 x_1^2 +x_2 x_3^2  + x_3 x_1^2 + x_3 x_2^2 - 6x_1 x_2 x_3}{x_1^2  + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - x_1 x_2 - x_1 x_3 - x_2 x_3 }$$

When sampling the variable, it looks very close to normal (1m samples, 100 bins):

[image]

I'm trying to understand how it can be so close, but the distribution of cubic forms in random variables isn't well documented or developed, and exact calculations for the ratio of forms seem to be very complicated, even in the case of two quadratic forms.

> Is there any simple approach to see why the variable distribution might be close to a normal?

---

It can be written more symmetrically as (Greg Martin):

$$ \sqrt2 \frac{ x_1 (x_2 - x_3)^2 + x_2 (x_3 - x_1)^2 + x_3 (x_1 - x_2)^2}{ (x_2 - x_3)^2 + (x_3 - x_1)^2 + (x_1 - x_2)^2} $$

Cross from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865959/ratio-of-cubic-and-quadratic-form-is-approximately-normal)

Comment: I suspect there's a typographical error in your first expression, because it is not symmetric in the variables.  The symmetrical form is highly suggestive, because $(x_2-x_3, x_3-x_1, x_1-x_2)$ is independent of $(x_1,x_2,x_3).$  Exploit that by integrating over the former variables.